# Could not load other mapping of entity in doctrine2 and zend 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Anyone, please help for me this issue. I'm the newbie of Doctrine. After some time to configure the doctrine(version 2.3) working with zend(version 1.10.8). All working fine except the last step. I have a table "test table" like this

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testtable` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

  INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  (1, 'test1'),
  (2, 'what');
```

This is the Entity annotations

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *  @ORM\Table(name="testtable")
 *  @ORM\Entity
 *
 */
class Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;



    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = (string)$name;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

**And in the controller of zend, i call this for testing:**

```
class DoctrineController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $em = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->em = \Zend_Registry::get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        try{
            $test = new Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test();
            $testMap = $this->em->getRepository('Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test')-       >findAll();

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($testMap);
            echo '</pre>';
            die();
        }catch(Exception $ex) {
            print_r($ex);die();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test Object
        (
            [name:Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test:private] => 
            [id:Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test:private] => 1
        )

    [1] => Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test Object
        (
            [name:Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test:private] => 
            [id:Tallcat_Doctrine_Entity_Test:private] => 2
        )

)
```

I don't know what wrong with the file name, it cannot load. I tried to save one record, it can save the Id, except the file Name.
Someone could help please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. The problem is:
The Doctrine cached the mapping before load, so the old code didn't update. So i restart the computer(stupid way) to clear cache. And it works perfect.
Thanks